# Wordpress Front Page not showing the page that I set as Front Page

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

My Wordpress website uses the Litespeed Cache plugin. When I have set up the main page for the website, when I check the display it still displays the WordPress theme default page instead of my new page.

I've cleared the cache on the browser and website but it still doesn't work.

Here the web link: https://java-experience.com

##### Here's what the front page looks like now:

[image]

---

##### And this is what should be displayed on the front page:

[image]

Comment: If you have recenlty updated the website's A record (IP address), could be propagation period, when I visited your site, it's showing the expected front page: https://snipboard.io/ohUQck.jpg

Comment: It loads fine for me. You probably saw the old version for the defined caching period in your litespeed plugin.